# Sending email through windows hosting?

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, asp-classic

How to create a email sending simple web service in Windows hosting in a file like `mailer.asp` as following `mailer.php` does in php environment. Gets 3 variables and sends email:

```
<?php
mail($_GET['email'], $_GET['subject'], $_GET['message']);
?>
```

I came up with following but it is giving 500 internal error:

```
<%
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject=Request.QueryString("subject")
myMail.From="mail@example.com"
myMail.To=Request.QueryString("email")
myMail.TextBody=Request.QueryString("message")
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
%>
```

Requirement is it should work in Windows environment, no matter it is VBscript, C#, ASP, or ASPX etc

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

config file to include the following

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="your email address" deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="your host" password="your password" userName="your username"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

and then the C# code can look something like

```
 var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
 var msg = new MailMessage();
 msg.To.Add("to email address");
 msg.Subject = "Some subject";
 msg.Body = "Some message";
 smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

This is something really simple you can expand from this as you wish